# What is the name of this Inequality

Tags: probability

I came across the inequality below and I don't know its name or how was it derived, any ideas?

Let Po($\lambda$) be a Poisson random variable with density $\lambda$. If $K> e^2 \lambda$ then:
$P[Po(\lambda)\ge K]\le e^{(-k/2 * \log(K/\lambda))}$

Answer (score 0):

It does look a bit like the [exponential Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Exponential_version).

Comment: Thank you, it make sense but the condition for $K$ is still throwing me away.